# SSRS missing cell values in preview report

Tags: reporting-services, cell, preview

I am using SSRS extension on Visual Studio 2019. While generating report and trying to see how final report would look like in **preview mode** parts of data are missing. I have looked this issue online and have come across solution to shrink width of the columns, however this makes my report look too shrink and it requires further formating when exported to excel. Is there any way to fix this issue so I could adjust column width to the size needed? I have tried to look for solution o this online, however couldn't find thread with answer that would help in this case.

Data types I use:
StudentName - nvarchar(50)

Marks - nvarchar(50)

Gender - float

Alignment:
First row (Example report of students) - Horizontal: Center, Vertical: Default
In any other cells it is Default.
Also padding is set to 2pt for every element and direction.

photo with adjusted column width - this is the **width I would like to achieve**, however data dissapears when width is enlarged

[image]

photo with shrunk columns - this table contains a**ll correct data**, however **columns don't have correct width** (data dissappears when column width is changed)

[image]

Below is photo of my dataset in query designer view:

[image: dataset query view]
This is the example of output I get when column width is changed data missing, empty row in between.

[image: This is the example of output I get when column width is changed (3 rows of]

Photo of table in design view
[image: Photo of table in design view]

Comment: Your screen shots are both the same

Comment: Thans for noticing Alan, edited now.

Comment: Rather than looking at resizing columns you should probably address why data is 'missing'. Can you edit the question to show an example of missing data and some sample data from your dataset for comparison. Show examples of what you get now vs what you want. Also, state what datatypes the columns are in the database. and any alignment properties oyu have set in the report

Comment: The only reason I am trying to find any sense there is because I am new user of the software and for time being this is the only thing that I have done that caused this immediate reaction. I have now edited the post including your suggestions, hope it will make some more sense now.

Comment: can you also include a picture of your table in design view?

Comment: Added from SSRS, do you require SQL photo also?

Comment: I also noticed in your two previews, the sort order is not always by StudentName. In your second to last picture of the column width with data missing, how come it's not sorted by the student name? It could be a problem with your data where you might have null values in student name/marks/gender. Like Alan said - it would help to provide a sample data.

Comment: you can also try this solution: https://www.wiseowl.co.uk/blog/s2577/report-builder-table-blank-rows.htm

Comment: @papermoon88 the last solution with the link to the wiseowl did work. When I change font to 10pt problem appears again which is something that I can't explain, however other sizes are working fine. I am actually studying SSRS following wiseowl video series, however with different dataset. This is why on my later photos some columns might not be sorted by student name. Also I do indeed have one line in DB with blank value for student name. I will investigate whether this may also be cause of the issue , however I would like to thanks for all your help provided on this!

Comment: Your table will display the result set from your query so if you don't want the blank values, you can use WHERE to exclude the null values.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced this a number of times and I just found what appears to be the solution while investigating somebody else's solution. They said to change the font size from 10 to 11 and Hey Presto, everything shows up.

While I was checking out the fonts, I noticed that some columns (not all columns were blank) had changed the Font from Arial to SegoeUI. I have never used SegoeUI so can only think of a misplaced mouse click or something.

Anyway I changed all the fonts back to Arial (and left the size at 10) and all my data was visible again.